# How do you show that a power series of $e^x$ at a point converges to $e^x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

My task is this:

Find Taylor-expansion of $e^x$ at the point $1$, the convergence interval $I$ and then show that the series converges to $e^x$.

My work so far:

By using $Te^x @ x= 1$ we should get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e(x-1)^n}{n!}$.  The ratio test tells us that:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{e(x-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}*\frac{n!}{e(x-1)^n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x-1}{n+1}\right|=0 \ \forall x.$$

Radius of convergence is therefor $I=\mathbb{R}.$ It's the last step I'm struggling with. Both teachers in my group told me the worst thing you want to hear; don't know. However they suggested a corollary from another chapter:

Suppose $f$ and it's $n+1$ derivatives is continious on $I=[a,x]$. Let $M$ be s.t. $\left|f^{(n+1)}(t)\right|\leq M \ \forall \:t$ between $a$ and $x$. Then $$\left|R_nf(x)\right|\leq\frac{M\left|x-a\right|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$

There are two problems that arrises with this according to my teachers. First one is that these assignements are placed at the very beginning of the current chapter and should be very easy and non tedious to solve. The second and probably more important point is that the material about this corollary is not in our syllabus. Sadly there are no examples of this exact problem in the current chapter.

To sum up; I'd like an answer to the last part of this task and to rephrase and generalize my question I would say: given a function and a point. Is there an easy way/method to show that it's taylor series converge to the function? I have a bunch of these tasks so it would be very nice to know in advace whether I have to read more or learn a shortcut method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What definition of $e^x$ are you using?

Comment: Could you please rephrase? Do you mean where I got my power series for $e$ i.e. taylor expansion or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e ?

Comment: Mainly the latter - You are being asked to show that a power series has certain properties - "converges to $e^x$ for all $x$". How you go about verifying this depends on how you have defined $e^x$. For example, $e^x$ is sometimes defined by its Taylor expansion at $x=0$, in which case you just have to manipulate the expression you have at $x=1$ until you reach the same form.

Comment: Well in that case the task is stated as it is and I suppose you can be free to chose any definition which suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following assumes that you already know $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n! $, ie the Taylor series of $e^x $ at $0$ (and that it converges to $e^x $).

Given this, simply note
$$
\sum e (x-1)^n /n! = e \cdot \sum (x-1)^n/n! = e \cdot e^{x-1} = e^x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} R_n(x)=0$ for all x,

where $\displaystyle R_n(x)=\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(x-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{e^c(x-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ and $c$ is a number between 1 and $x$.

1) If $x< 1$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}R_n(x)=0$ since $\displaystyle |R_n(x)|< \frac{e|x-1|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ (since $e^c< e$) and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x-1|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=0$

2) If $x>1$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}R_n(x)=0$ since $\displaystyle |R_n(x)|< \frac{e^x|x-1|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ (since $e^c<e^x$) and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x-1|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=0$

(See http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/Formulas4RemainderTaylorSeries5ET.pdf)